# Numerical stability of ODE system

Tags: numerical-methods, ode, runge-kutta, numerical-stability

I have to perform a numerical solving of an ODE system which has the following form:

```
du_j/dt = f_1(u_j, v_j, t) + g_1(t)v_(j-1) + h_1(t)v_(j+1),

dv_j/dt = f_2(u_j, v_j, t) + g_2(t)u_(j-1) + h_2(t)u_(j+1),
```

where `u_j(t)` and `v_j(t)` are complex-valued scalar functions of time `t`, `f_i` and `g_i` are given functions, and `j = -N,..N`. This is an initial value problem and the task is to find the solution at a certain time `T`.

If `g_i(t) = h_i(t) = 0`, then the equations for different values of `j` can be solved independently. In this case I obtain a stable and accurate solutions with the aid of the fourth-order Runge-Kutta method. However, once I turn on the couplings, the results become very unstable with respect to the time grid step and explicit form of the functions `g_i`, `h_i`.

I guess it is reasonable to try to employ an implicit Runge-Kutta scheme, which might be stable in such a case, but if I do so, I will have to evaluate the inverse of a huge matrix of size `4*N*c`, where `c` depends on the order of the method (e. g. `c = 3` for the Gauss–Legendre method) at each step. Of course, the matrix will mostly contain zeros and have a block tridiagonal form but it still seems to be very time-consuming.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a stable explicit method which works even when the coupling functions `g_i` and `h_i` are (very) large?
2. If an implicit method is, indeed, a good solution, what is the fastest method of the inversion of a block tridiagonal matrix? At the moment I just perform a simple Gauss method avoiding redundant operations which arise due to the specific structure of the matrix.

Additional info and details that might help us:

- I use Fortran 95.
- I currently consider `g_1(t) = h_1(t) = g_2(t) = h_2(t) = -iAF(t)sin(omega*t)`, where `i` is the imaginary unit, `A` and `omega` are given constants, and `F(t)` is a smooth envelope going slowly, first, from 0 to 1 and then from 1 to 0, so `F(0) = F(T) = 0`.
- Initially `u_j = v_j = 0` unless `j = 0`. The functions `u_j` and `v_j` with great absolute values of `j` are extremely small for all `t`, so the initial peak does not reach the "boundaries".

Answer (score 0):

To 1) There will be no stable explicit method if your functions are very large. This is due to the fact that the area of stability of explicit (Runge-Kutta) methods is compact.

To 2) If your matrices are larger then 100x100 you could use this method:
[Inverses of Block Tridiagonal Matrices and Rounding Errors](https://www.emis.de/journals/BMMSS/pdf/v34n2/v34n2p10.pdf).